# preg_replace issue. Character class inside other character class

Tags: php, regex

I have a fragment in text like

```
;flat
CID_999999 = 99999999
CID_999999 = 99999999
CID_999999 = 99999999
CID_999999 = 99999999
```

where 999999 are some numbers. I want to find this fragment by regexp.
When I use this regex:

```
preg_replace('/;flat[\s\r\n]+[CID_0-9]+\s=\s[0-9]+\n/','REPLACEMENT',$content);
```

it replaces `;flat` and first `CID` string. 
So, I suppose that if I put `[CID_0-9]+\s=\s[0-9]+\n` part in character class `[]+`it will remove all `CID` strings. But if I do it it doesn't replace anything. So I don't understand something in regex. What am I doing wrong?
I thought that expected output is clear, but ok. I should replace all fragment by REPLACEMENT.

Comment: What is the expected output?Which `9999999` you want to find

Comment: All of them. All fragments CID_9999 = 9999 after ;flat and before next ;

Comment: You're misunderstanding character classes. They don't match what's inside multiple times, they match _one_ character out of all those inside the square braces. If you want to repeatedly match `[CID_0-9]+\s=\s[0-9]+\n`, make it a group and add `+` at the end: `(?:[CID_0-9]+\s=\s[0-9]+\n)+`. Also, `[CID_0-9]+` should be `CID_[0-9]+`.

Comment: Well, actually your answer is what I wanted. I solved my problem by some trick (I have 2 fragmetns started with ;flat, I replaced both of then on REPLACEMENT, than changend REPLACEMENT+needed fragmenet on one fragment and then REPLACEMENT on other fragment). So I decided just to mark vks answer. I'm sure that your answer will be usefull for me in future. So I'll mark it if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a character class (`[...]`); you need a group (`(...)`). Your code should look like this:

```
preg_replace('/;flat[\s\r\n]+([CID_0-9]+\s=\s[0-9]+\n?)+/', 'REPLACEMENT', $content);
```

Note the `?` at the end, just in case your last line isn't terminated with a new line (`\n`) character.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zH9tW9/1)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use lookbehind if you are trying to match just the digits after the `=` and before the newline
2. For more accurate matching use `CID[0-9]+` rather than `[CID0-9]+`

   ```
   preg_replace('/(?<;flat[\s\r\n]+CID_[0-9]+\s=\s)[0-9]+(?=\n)/','REPLACEMENT',$content);
   ```

Comment: could you explain this `(?<;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
;flat\s*|(?!^)\G(CID_\d+\s*=\s*\d+\s*)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/7

```
$re = "/;flat\\s*|(?!^)\\G(CID_\\d+\\s*=\\s*\\d+\\s*)/";
$str = ";flat\nCID_999999 = 99999999\nCID_999999 = 99999999\nCID_999999 = 99999999\nCID_999999 = 99999999\n;";
$subst = "$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: What is the last branch `\G;` for? It seems redundant to me

Comment: @nhahtdh OP mentioned some `next;` or some definite closure but i guess he doesnt need it anyways

Comment: I read OP's comment as "after `;flat` and before the next semi-colon `;`". There should be no problem with your regex, then. Just remove the `next` in your example `$str`

Comment: @SergeyScopin which case did not work.Can you post that?